# Implementing  real time video chat using Android

Tags: android, voip

Does anyone know how to implement voice/video over IP in a android application ?

I am trying to understand how it works and should be done. what is the best technology to do that ? is there any good tutorial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out SipDroid. It does pretty much what you want and is free open source software. You can check out their code and go from there. http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/